# Prevent command from running

Tags: python, printing, terminate

How would I stop the last print statement from running if the user inputs 'no' to print(M1)? I want the program to finish when M1 is printed. I get the error 
"NameError: name 'TaxCode' is not defined" when user inputs 'no' because of declaring 'TaxCode' in if block.
Thank you.

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
while True:
    try:
        income = int(input("What is your income? ($) "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid input\nPlease enter a figure")
        continue
    else:
        break

M1  = "This program cannot determine your tax code. Please use the program for secondary income "

print("Please answer the questions with 'yes' and 'no'")


Q1=input("Do you receive an income tested benefit? ")
while Q1 != "yes" and Q1 != "no":
    print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
    Q1=input("Do you recieve an income tested benefit? ")
    if Q1=="yes":
                 Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
                 while Q2 != "yes" and Q2 != "no":
                     print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
                     Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
                      if Q2=="yes":
                                TaxCode = "M"
                      elif Q2=="no":
                                  print (M1)

print("Thanks for answering the questions.",name,"Your tax code is ",TaxCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `TaxCode` with empty value before if statement in order to prevent `NameError`. Such that `TaxCode =''`

You can use `exit(0)` to terminate the program here number inside () refers to success/failure. Same like exit status in linux. So your code will be

```
while Q1 != "yes" and Q1 != "no":
    print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
    Q1=input("Do you recieve an income tested benefit? ")
    if Q1=="yes":
        Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
         while Q2 != "yes" and Q2 != "no":
             print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
             Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
             TaxCode='' #define it before using
             if Q2=="yes":
                 TaxCode = "M"
             elif Q2=="no":
                  print (M1)
                  exit(0) # terminates program and raises success non-zero value refers failure.

print("Thanks for answering the questions.",name,"Your tax code is ",TaxCode)
```

If you use the above code in a function and you want to stop the function you can use `return` statement to skip printing last line by returning `None` so in that case your code will be.

```
while Q1 != "yes" and Q1 != "no":
    print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
    Q1=input("Do you recieve an income tested benefit? ")
    if Q1=="yes":
        Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
         while Q2 != "yes" and Q2 != "no":
             print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
             Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
             TaxCode='' #define it before using
             if Q2=="yes":
                 TaxCode = "M"
             elif Q2=="no":
                  print (M1)
                  return None # skips print and returns to calling function.
print("Thanks for answering the questions.",name,"Your tax code is ",TaxCode)
```

You can use either `exit` or `return` according to your logic since you are not clear whether this code is used in a function or main I explained both.

Comment: If any of the solution provided solves your problem accept it as answer or if it is helpful upvote it. People spend their time in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should define 'TaxCode' outside the if statement.

For example,

```
TaxCode = ""
Q1=input("Do you receive an income tested benefit? ")
while Q1 != "yes" and Q1 != "no":
    print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
    Q1=input("Do you recieve an income tested benefit? ")
if Q1=="yes":
                 Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
                 while Q2 != "yes" and Q2 != "no":
                     print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
                     Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
                 if Q2=="yes":
                                TaxCode = "M"
                 elif Q2=="no":
                                  print (M1)

print("Thanks for answering the questions.",name,"Your tax code is ",TaxCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Navieclipse mentioned, you need to define TaxCode before using it.

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
while True:
    try:
        income = int(input("What is your income? ($) "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid input\nPlease enter a figure")
        continue
    else:
        break

TaxCode = ""
M1  = "This program cannot determine your tax code. Please use the program for secondary income "

print("Please answer the questions with 'yes' and 'no'")

while True:
    Q1=input("Do you receive an income tested benefit? ")
    if Q1 == "yes":
        Q2=input("Is this tax code for the income tested benefit? ")
        if Q2 == "yes":
            TaxCode = "Test"
            print("Thanks for answering the questions, "+ name + ", " + "your tax code is " + TaxCode + ".")
            break
        elif Q2 == 'no':
            print(M1)
            break
    else:
        print("\nPlease enter either 'yes' or 'no'")
```

Also, formatting it after you copy it here would make it easier to read.